# Spring MVC Test: how to add description to andExpect

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-test, hamcrest, junit5

In a test example

```
@Test
public void aSampleTest() {
    this.mockMvc
      .perform(get("/ultimateQuestion"))
      .andExpect(jsonPath("$.meaningOfLife", is("42"));
}
```

... is it possible to add a (failing) test description, so that a failing test has a human-readable message rather than just

```
Expected: is "42"
   but was 24
```

I mean, similar to

```
assertTrue(boolean condition, String message)
```

as opposed to

```
assertTrue(boolean condition)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is currently no way to customize the failure "reason".

It is hard coded to `"JSON path \"" + this.expression + "\""` in `org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.assertValue(String, Matcher<T>)`, where `this.expression` is the JsonPath expression you supply (e.g., `"$.meaningOfLife"` in your example).